# LINQ extract dataTable information

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable with these 2 columns of intereset:

```
Category Sum
cat1     10
cat1     15
cat2     20
cat2     25
cat3     30
cat3     35
```

I want to find with LINQ each first row that has a different category than “cat1” and extract the category name and sum.
So to have as output “cat2”-20 and “cat3”-30. This output can be of any kind, dictionary,dataTable,etc.

**This could be split into LINQ queries, 1 to find all the different categories and 1 to find the sum.**

Can you help ?

Comment: Assuming you have a list of a type with properties `Category` and `Sum`, this would work: `list.Where(x => x.Category != "cat1").GroupBy(x => x.Category, (key, rows) => rows.First())`

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ (Main DataTable to another DataTable which is your Extracted data)

```
DataTable extractedDT = new DataTable();
DataRow dtr;
extractedDT.Columns.Add("Category");
extractedDT.Columns.Add("Sum");

yourMainDataTableCollection.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(w => w.Field<string>("Category") != "Cat1")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(f =>
            {
                dtr = extractedDT.NewRow();

                dtr["Category"] = f.ItemArray[0];
                dtr["sum"] = f.ItemArray[1];

                extractedDT.Rows.Add(dtr);
            });
```

extractedDT is your collection output.